# No implementation for `{integer} % &std::ops::Range<{integer}>`

Tags: rust

I understand the error, but still have no idea how to cast `i` to `u32/integer`.

```rust
let n = 2;
for i in [1..10].into_iter() {
  if n % i == 0 {
    ...
  }
}
```

`if n % (i as u32) == 0` doesn't work

> help: the trait `std::ops::Rem<&std::ops::Range<{integer}>>` is not implemented for `{integer}`

Comment: If you want to iterate on some u32, you can use `for i in 1u32..10u32`

Answer (score 8):

In your code, `[1..10]` is actually a fixed-size array with a range `1..10` as its only element. You want to iterate over range itself rather than that 1-element array:

```rust
let n = 2;
for i in 1..10 {
  if n % i == 0 {
    ...
  }
}
```